# How do I change the iOS icon in the open app list in Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, icons, appicon

How do I change the Icon in the open app list?  I've filled in all of the icons in the Assets.xcassets file. Where else do I need to look?

[image]

Comment: Try uninstalling your app from the device and reinstall it.

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work. The Xamarin logo still shows up.  Could it be because I'm running it in through Visual Studio?

Comment: @megalodon Hi, you could share the screenshot of `Assets.xcassets` here to check. And you'd better clean project in Visual studio, and delete `bin` and `obj` folder bellow iOS solution to have a try whether it works.